# Moved presale ether after the fork how do I split?

Tags: ether, ethereum-classic, hardforks, presale, removedb

I bought ether at the presale and moved it to another address after the fork. I still have the original wallet backup, but I'm uncertian on the process to claim ETC. When I scan my Address on Ethereum Classic Block Explorer I have a ETC Balance. But I have moved almost all my ETH out of the same address with a balance of just 0.02 ETH. Can I claim ETC? If so How?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Classic Ether wallet](https://ethereumproject.github.io/etherwallet/) to access Ether with your original wallet. Since you moved your Ether after the fork, the ETC will still be there (as you mention).

Other wallets are available if you prefer, see [Ethereum Classic github](https://ethereumclassic.github.io/).